# Is it possible to skip overriden methods code when based on base code

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

Ive got quick c# question. 
If I have method like this

```
    protected virtual void Delete(Guid? guidId)
    {
    }
```

Then I override it like this

```
    protected override void Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
          code goes here 
        }
    }
```

I could place that if statement inside the base method like this

```
    protected virtual void Delete(Guid? guidId)
    { 
        if (id != null)
        {
          code goes here 
        }
    }
```

And then call it like this

```
    protected override void Delete(Guid? id)
    {
      base.Delete(id);
      code goes here  
    }
```

But now in the overridden method, I don’t want to carry on if the base method did not go inside that if statement. 
I was just wondering if this was possible. Thank you :)

Comment: Having the method return a *bool* jumps to mind as a simple workaround.

Comment: And why don´t you re-check this condition in your derived class?

Comment: @HimBromBeere because the id must never be null, and by making a call to base to check that, my large delete method with lots of nested if's will have one indentation less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for the [Template Method pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html), also often known as *hook methods*.

```
public class Base 
{
    protected void Delete(Guid? id)
    { 
        if (id != null)
        {
           //code goes here

           //execute hook only if id is not null
           OnDelete(id);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDelete(Guid? guid) {}
}


public class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void OnDelete(Guid? guid)
    {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

If you want to force all base classes to implement the hook, make the method abstract.
Otherwise, if implementing the hook is optional, define it as an empty method, as I've done above.

This pattern employs a very powerful principle: the [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle). *Don't call us, we'll call you!* The derived class doesn't call the base class, as in your example - instead, the base class will call the derived class *if* appropriate.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply it looks interesting, but I dont quite get how it works. Because the override void OnDelete is not calling at any point Delete from the base to see whether that id is not null. Can you expand on this please? I'd like to know what do I do inside of ovveride OnDelete to make sure that "if" check was done. I'd like protected override void OnDelete(Guid? guid)
    {

    } this to jump out of the method if guid was null, instead if i call Delete inside it, it will go to next line no matter what. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @adminSoftDK The `Delete` method on the base class does the check for you. The `OnDelete` method will only be called if the id is not null, so you can just dump your business logic into the `OnDelete` override and not worry about checking the id. This a very good pattern for scenarios like yours, and frameworks such as WPF, WinForms, WinRT use it all over the place (e.g., `OnPageLoaded` hooks).

Comment: Also, you can probably make `Delete` a private method now. The base class does not need to call it.

Comment: It looks like a great pattern (and I never heard of it), because im checking for similar null values all over the place (in a WPF). However I still dont see what is telling (calling) the Delete method to be executed. I guess I just need to read about this pattern, starting from the link you provided :)

Comment: @adminSoftDK In your original code, who was calling the `Delete` method?

Comment: it is a delegate command from prism that is calling it. So it is a button that is bound to that command.                             DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand<Guid?>(Delete);           Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/> so a button is bound to that command and then command calls the Delete method

Comment: @adminSoftDK So, the delegate will still be able to call your `Delete` method :) When the `Delete` method executes, it'll check if the id is null - if it's not null, it'll call your `OnDelete` hook defined in the derived class. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: I see, yes it makes sense now. I need to test it, if it works then it'll be great add on to my project.

Comment: I accepted your answer, as I like it more :). Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Change the method to return a `bool` to indicate if the branch was taken, e.g.:

```
class Base
{
    protected virtual bool Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (id != null)
        {
            // ...

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

internal class Derived : Base
{
    protected override bool Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (!base.Delete(id))
            return false;

        // ...

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I appreciated it, I decided I stick with if(id != null) as there is no need in my case to return anything. However i've learned small interesting approach from this post :) Rgs